# AppImage not launching after installing AppImageLauncher

Tags: 22.04, appimage

I have an AppImage: `HTTPie-2023.3.2.AppImage`

It ran perfectly, but then I installed the [AppImageLuncher](https://github.com/TheAssassin/AppImageLauncher/releases):

`sudo dpkg -i appimagelauncher.deb` (appimagelauncher_2.2.0-travis995.0f91801.bionic_i386.deb)

Now every time I try to run the AppImage I got this error:

```shell
> ./HTTPie-2023.3.2.AppImage 
Gtk-Message: 19:45:36.773: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: 19:45:36.773: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/appimagelauncher/libbinfmt-bypass-preload.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
execv error: No such file or directory
```

I already tried to install some packages, but not successfully:

`sudo apt install libfuse2`

`sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module`

And I have no clue about `LD_PRELOAD`.

So, could someone help me with this problem?

Comment: Have you tried removing AppImageLauncher and running the AppImage? What else did you do after installing the package? The package you installed is for the i386 architecture, a.k.a, it's 32-bits, and it's for 18.04, but the tag on your question says 22.04. Are you running 22.04 32-bits?

Comment: So, apparently the problem was the version of the AppImageLauncher, after installing that specific version, all was working, and after installing the previous stable version, also working, so I guess that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, apparently the problem was the version of the AppImageLauncher, after installing that specific version, all was working, and after installing the previous stable version, also working, so I guess that's it.